# LINQ - ENTITY: Need to return a list of count of rows in ANOTHER table

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I have a system with a table PRODUCTS and FAULTS. Each product can have a number of faults (the fault table has a foreign key ProductID). I need to get a list of aproximately ten products with the most number of faults. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to be work (the fields that i need are the product name, price, id and the number of faults):

```
      return (from p in Entity.Products
                join f in Entity.Faults
                on p.ProductID equals f.ProductID
                group f by new { f.ProductID, p.Name, p.Price } into product
                select new CountFaultView()
                {
                    ProductID = product.Key.ProductID,
                    Name = product.Key.Name,
                    Price = product.Key.Price,
                    FaultsCount = product.Key.Name.Count()
                }
                ).OrderByDescending(x => x.FaultsCount).Take(10);

    }
```

I am TRYING to count the number of times that the name is displayed but obviously I seem to be getting something wrong ;o

Comment: can you post what result you are getting ? also, have you tried returning on the 'product' to see if that works first then try projecting into CountFaultView.

Comment: the result is null, i'll try with the product

Comment: Try `FaultsCount = product.Count()`

Comment: Works like that, thanks!